# Is there a way to return rows from two tables where I only need the duplicate values from one column? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Is there a way to return rows from two tables where I only need the duplicate values from one column in SQL?

Basically I have two tables I have joined together, People_Details & People_Holidays. I need to return most columns from these tables but for one column which is the People_ID column I need to return values where there is more than one entry. So for example:
I don't want these rows:
35
57
132

I do want:
227
227
227
333
333
333
333

The reason for this is the other details will be different.

Any help much appreciated.

I have tried the having clause people_ID > 1 etc. but no luck so far.

Comment: Can you provide the files for this and perhaps the expected result?
If so, I can go through it and get you a better result than simply giving you some theorycraft.

Comment: We have no way to know how your data looks like, so we cannot help you to achieve your wanted result. It would be a great help to you if you edit your question and provide us with sample data, and with the logic to get from the sample data to your wanted result. Also show what you have tried already

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Stacey96 - Remember we can't see your schema. Without any context, those are just a list of numbers. We have no idea why the number 35 should be ignored, but not 227, or what SQL query will return those results.  To avoid an extended round of "guessing", you need to provide some context. Specifically in the form of a (small) example. Post the CREATE TABLE statement, a few sample rows (as INSERT statements) and the desired result, all as text (not screen shots).